# Action buttons for modal in view and edit mode

Tags: buttons, modal

I have a modal that displays the details of an user or product (view mode). You can click the edit button to show the form (edit mode).

[image]

Pressing Cancel will bring you back to View mode. And clicking close will close the modal (same as clicking X).

I'm not sure if this is good UI/UX. I guess I'm worried that the user will think that Cancel actually closes the modal. Or maybe that won't be an issue since they will eventually see the Close button anyway?

Comment: Is the display mode necessary at all, and if so, why is it a modal? Should it block what's behind it? Modals get overused a lot and that always causes these types of design issues, so it might be a good idea to rethink that.

Comment: @jazZRo Actually, it could just be a profile page. You suggest I just turn it into a profile page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can skip close button on view mode which will give user clear idea how to navigate